# Two Remove asterisk sign via Jquery from a label

Tags: jquery, html

In a paragraph I have a label that has two asterisk (*) signs. On page Load I want to check if it has two asterisk (**) signs then I want to remove one of them

My HTML looks like:

```
<p>
    <label for="xyz">**Required</label>
</p>
```

How is it done via jquery?

Comment: Why in first place there is two asterisks? If you render it server side, then fix it server side

Comment: What is your effort and code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** method with callback to iterate and use **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method to update the text.

```js
// get all label which contains 2 adjuscent *
$('label:contains("**")').text(function(i, txt) {
  // iterate over them, replace and update 
  return txt.replace('**', '*');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="xyz">**Required</label>
</p>
```

Comment: Pranav, Script is not working properly. Can you please add it in a function and assist me

Comment: @user4956321 : glad to help  :)